# Manually downloaded android obb file, deleted after app update through Play Store

Tags: java, android, apk-expansion-files

in my app I handle obb extension files download and hosting manually.

I did not upload it in app store, because I use more than one obb files depending on the specific user needs, so I cannot just use a single obb file that is uploaded on play store for the user to download.

I also manage manually obb files rename, so they can be usable for the app, as user can have more than one obb files downloaded and switch between them while app is renaming the obb accordingly.

My issue is, that after a normal update through Play Store, the obb file gets deleted, thus requiring user to re-download it.

I would be happy to know why this is happening or a way to avoid it.

Please note, that I don't have any obb file uploaded on Play Store, because it wouldn't serve my needs. Once user opens the app, chooses appropriate extension to use and then download it through my app.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think issue's with the Play Store submissions system should be posted on Stack Overflow. It's probably best to contact Google or use one of their support options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your OBB is not downloaded from the Play Store, then I wouldn't stick it in the Play OBB directory. The directory is `<shared-storage>/Android/obb/<package-name>/` and the Play store assumes it has a duty to keep this directory clean as part of the update process, so the user isn't left with a bunch of unnecessary OBB files.

If you want to download the files yourself, and take care of the updates yourself, just put the files in another directory. I'd recommend reading [the docs on developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) to help you choose the best location.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for the answer, I will accept it as correct, as I wanted to confirm that this is happening.

Comment: Only problem with copying obbs elsewhere is that for an obb to be usable, it has to be inside obb dir. Sticking there it will be deleted on an update, but I will check the possibility my app needs it inside obb dir, only when the initialization in happening, and after init move it back to other dir. Any comments on that will be appreciated, thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean for an OBB to  be usable? An OBB  is an "Opaque Binary Blob", ie, it's just a file of data. It can be used from any directory, it's just data. Unless you are using some sort of 3rd party plugin code that expects it to live in particular location.

Comment: Thanks for your pertinent comment. You got it right, my case involves an external jar file expecting OBB to be in specific location, so this is another issue. Your help was valuable, now I know how to handle multiple manually downloaded extension files, I need to keep them in other location than <shared-storage>/Android/obb/<package-name> folder.